# Conversion of row value counts to column in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows,

```
Name   value
A        0
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        0
B        0
B        3
C        5
```

I want the following output,

```
Name     0     0<X<2     2-4     5 and above
A        1       1        2       0
B        2       0        1       0
C        0       0        0       1
```

I want the new columns to be created and counts of the rows to fall into it. I have tried reshape for it. But it is changing the structure, but count is not working. Can anybody help me in doing this?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to include what you've tried.

Comment: @RichardScriven Why try when the people at the SO helpdesk give you personalized service anyway?

Comment: @RichardScriven Apologies for not including it. Going forward will include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `cut`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, gr := cut(value, breaks=c(-1, 0, 2, 4, Inf), 
         labels=c(0, '0<X<2', '2-4', '5 and above'))]
dcast(df1, Name~gr)
#     Name 0 0<X<2 2-4 5 and above
#1:    A 1   2   1           0
#2:    B 2   0   1           0
#3:    C 0   0   0           1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `class` column in your `dataframe`, then use `table()`:

```
df <- read.table(text="Name   value
A        0
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        0
B        0
B        3
C        5", header=T)

df[df$value==0, 'class'] <- "0"
df[df$value==1, 'class'] <- "0<X<2"
df[df$value>=2&df$value<=4, 'class'] <- "2-4"
df[df$value>4, 'class'] <- "5 and above"
table(df$Name, df$class)


    0 0<X<2 2-4 5 and above
  A 1     1   2           0
  B 2     0   1           0
  C 0     0   0           1
```

Answer (score 1):

And just for fun:

```
f <- function(x) c(sum(x == 0), sum(x > 0 & x < 2), sum(x >= 2  & x <= 4), sum(x > 5))

t(sapply(split(df$value, df$Name), f))
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
A    1    1    2    0
B    2    0    1    0
C    0    0    0    0
```